# How to display huge amount of data a tooltip

Tags: html, tooltip

I am displaying 400 account names in the tooltip of a span element.

```
<input type="button" value="AccountList" id="accountlist" title="[400 names here]" />
```

But it is displaying only a part of it, it is not displaying all 400 account names. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I dont think you have supplied enough information for anyone to help you

Comment: I cleaned up the question. OP incorrectly assumed it to be a JSF specific problem (or didn't seem to realize that JSF is in the context of this problem merely a HTML code generator), hereby making the question confusing. Mihir, once you get the answer from HTML experts (and it requires changes in HTML .. ;) ), then it's matter of altering the JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the browser's length limit on the title attribute. The limit depends on the browser. Microsoft (IE) publishes its limit as 512. I don't think we have the official published limits for the other browsers, but empirically it doesn't seem like a lot more than that.

You can solve it by not relying on the browser's "tool tip", but build your own custom one using CSS. Look [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/) for a simple tutorial.